# FigureCanvasWxAgg not resizing properly in panel (or notebook) in linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, wxpython

I've written a program in wxpython that works just fine in windows but when tested in lunix I have some Display issues that that all occur in linux.

Here is a testapp that demonstrates the problem with the resizing of the FigureCanvasWxAgg in a panel, as seen the panel it self follows the resizingevent but the FigureCanvasWxAgg doesn't follow, this however is not a problem in Windows.

```
import wx
import matplotlib.figure as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import wx.lib.inspection

class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.figure = plt.Figure()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, 1)
        self.figurepanel = FigureCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes1 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        frame_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        frame_box.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
        frame_box.Add(self.panel, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=2)
        frame_box.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
        main_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_box.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
        main_box.Add(frame_box, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=1)
        main_box.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
        self.SetSizer(main_box)
        self.Show()
        self.Layout()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    Test()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I would be very grateful to have answered is:

- How do I resolve this issue of reszing FigureCanvasWxAgg in linux
- Is there any difference in the general way of GUI programming with wxPython on  Windows and in Linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I fixed the problem. The problem is caused by the wx.EVT_SIZE witch seems to be automatic in Windows but not in Linux. So to fix the problem in Linux all you have to do is to bind the the wx.Panel  to the wx.EVT_SIZE and then define an apropriate eventhandler that takes care of the resizing.
What did the trick for me was:

```
#code beneath is a part if the __init__ metod
self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
self.figurepanel = FigureCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.figure)
self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)
....
#the eventhandler for the panel. The method resizes the the figurepanel and the figure.
def on_size(self, event):
    pix = self.panel.GetClientSize()
    self.figure.set_size_inches(pix[0]/self.figure.get_dpi(),
                                pix[1]/self.figure.get_dpi())
    x,y = self.panel.GetSize()  
    self.figurepanel.SetSize((x-1, y-1))
    self.figurepanel.SetSize((x, y))
    self.figurepanel.draw()
    event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with the code you posted:

1. You have horizontal and vertical spacer that expand as needed, which causes the central region to remain the same shape
2. `self.figurepanel` is not part of any sizer, which means it will *not* resize even if its container, `self.panel` does.

The code below produces a window filled by plot that resizes with the window:

```
import wx
import matplotlib.figure as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import wx.lib.inspection

class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, 1)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('RED')

        self.figure = plt.Figure()
        self.axes1 = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.figurepanel = FigureCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.figure)

        main_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_box.Add(self.figurepanel, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=1)
        self.panel.SetSizer(main_box)

        frame_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        frame_box.Add(self.panel, flag=wx.EXPAND, proportion=1)

        self.SetSizer(frame_box)
        self.Show()
        self.Layout()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    Test()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There is no need to do any manual resizing yourself, and there is no problem, I think, with resize event propagation. If there is there would be a lot more breakage than what you are seeing.